# calculate the difference between first and last value of each Id and count those with 10% decrease in DAX Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas

have a simple table like this

```
         ID   value    date
         A     100     2020-01-01
         B     80      2019-01-01 
         A     90      2022-01-01
         A     130     2021-01-01
         B     100     2021-01-01
```

and want to know how many IDs had 10% increase within a selected time period, IDs might not necessarily have an entry on Min(Date) or Max(Date), I'd like to know the difference between first and last value within the selected time period

I came up with something like this but not sure if it's working :

```
   Measure=

   Var FirstValue= 
    SUMX (
    VALUES( table [ID] ),
    CALCULATE ( MIN ( table[value]), FIRSTDATE ( 'Date'[DATE] ) )
      )

   Var LastValue  = 
   SUMX (
   VALUES( table[ID] ),
   CALCULATE ( MIN ( table[value] ), LASTDATE ( 'Date'[DATE]) )
   )

  Return sumx(table,if( (FirstValue -LastValue  )/FirstValue> 0.1 , 1,0)
   )
```

Comment: Over which values do you judge whether there was a 10% increase or not? For example, within the period 2020-01-01 to 2022-01-01, A had values of 100, 130 and 90. What is your expected result here and why?

Comment: @JosWoolley I need to calculate the difference between first and last within the selected time period and count IDs with 10% decrease

Comment: @JosWoolley in that case, assuming we're looking at a date range (2018- 2022) A's first value will be 100 and last value will be 90 which means it had 10% decrease and should be counted